# How to unzip .gz files via gdal?

Tags: gdal

I have a lot of .gz files that contain imagery and I'm going to unzip them.
I was wondering if that could be done via GDAL.

Comment: Probably you do not need to unzip at all. Start with `gdalinfo /vsigzip/your_archive.gz`. What do you see?

Comment: @user30184 Thank you. I tried that before, but I don't know where to include the path. this doesn't work I reckon I'm missing somthing or ....gdalinfo /vsigzip/E:/UM2014_RGBI/RGBI_image.gz/RGBI_image

Comment: What does plain `gdalinfo /vsigzip/E:/UM2014_RGBI/RGBI_image.gz`show?

Comment: @user30184 It says "ERROR 4: RGBI_image.gz not recognised as supported file format. gdalinfo failed unable to open 'gdalinfo /vsigzip/E:/UM2014_RGBI/RGBI_image.gz'

Comment: Which GDAL version do you have?

Comment: @user30184, GDAL-1.11.3.win-amd64.

Comment: I don't know how to check if some GDAL build has support for /vsigzip/. I would test it with some small tiff file first. Compress it into .gz and into .zip and try what gdalinfo reports. Put the archive into your working directory to be sure that any character in the file path does not make troubles. I use a development build from gisinternals.com and it works for me.

Comment: @Matt Your file "RGBI_image.gz" looks **.gz** but it may be **.tar.gz** file. If it is the case, you need to change the extension so that the filename becomes "RGBI_image.tar.gz". Then try **/vsitar/** instead of **/vsigzip**. It also requires original filename(s) archived into the .gz (or .tar.gz) file. If your file has only one image file, your command will be **gdalinfo /vsitar/E:/UM2014_RGBI/RGBI_image.tar.gz/RGBI_image.xxx**.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the raster image file driver (for whatever kind of file `RGBI_image` is) does not support the "large file API," which is required for virtual file systems. [You can read more about that at gdal.org.](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#drivers-supporting-virtual-file-systems)

You could decompress the file in Python and open it using the GDAL Python API:

```py
import gzip
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from osgeo import gdal

with gzip.open('E:/UM2014_RGBI/RGBI_image.gz', 'rb') as file:
    tmp = NamedTemporaryFile()
    tmp.write(file.read())
ds = gdal.Open(tmp.name)
```

Writing the file buffer to a `NamedTemporaryFile` is necessary as `gdal.Open()` can only look for a file that exists on the file system; it can't read the buffer directly. In my experience, this is still pretty fast and definitely worth avoiding the time and disk space required to decompress and extract the files.

For hierarchical files/ files with SubDatasets, e.g.:

```py
ds = gdal.Open(f'HDF5:{tmp.name}:Dataset')
```