# Load gzipped HDF5 layer without decompressing using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, command-line, gdalinfo, hdf5

I am interested in loading a VIIRS raster that's contained in a gzipped H5 file, but I get an error. I am using the following command to get the info:

```
gdalinfo HDF5:"/vsigzip/imagery/viirs/test3/VIIRS-SDR_VIIRS-Moderate-Resolution-Band-10-SDR_20200923_78694/SVM10_npp_d20200923_t0333337_e0339141_b46148_c20200923073914810642_noac_ops.h5.gz"://All_Data/VIIRS-M10-SDR_All/Radiance
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR 4: `HDF5:/vsigzip/imagery/viirs/test3/VIIRS-SDR_VIIRS-Moderate-Resolution-Band-10-SDR_20200923_78694/SVM10_npp_d20200923_t0333337_e0339141_b46148_c20200923073914810642_noac_ops.h5.gz://All_Data/VIIRS-M10-SDR_All/Radiance' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

I know this path works because if I use it with the python bindings, I can load everything correctly. Also, the gdalinfo command works if I de-compress the h5 file first, but this is not practical for my application, and I would like to make it work with the compressed file.

Comment: try using /`vsigzip/` https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html

Comment: See this related question and answer: [How to unzip .gz files via gdal?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214848/how-to-unzip-gz-files-via-gdal)